# Proving that an alternating sum of arctangents is bounded

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, inequality, convergence-divergence

I am struggling with the following question - how do I prove that a series like the following is bounded?

$$\sum_{n=1}^{ \infty} (-1)^n\arctan\left(\frac{3n^2}{2n+1}\right) $$

I just started learning about sums, so I'm trying to understand techniques to prove things like this. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**. One may write
$$
 (-1)^n\arctan\left(\frac{3n^2}{2n+1}\right)=(-1)^n\frac \pi2 - (-1)^n\arctan\left(\frac{2}{3n}+\frac{1}{3n^2}\right)
$$ then
$$
\left|\sum_{n=1}^N(-1)^n\frac \pi2\right|\le \frac \pi2 \cdot \left|\sum_{n=1}^N(-1)^n\right|\le \frac \pi2 \cdot 2=\pi
$$ and, by applying the [Dirichlet test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test),
$$
\left|\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\arctan\left(\frac{2}{3n}+\frac{1}{3n^2}\right)\right|=C<\infty
$$ giving
$$
\left|\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\arctan\left(\frac{3n^2}{2n+1}\right)\right|\le \pi+C.
$$

Comment: I don't understand why the first two terms are equal

Comment: One has $$\arctan x=\frac \pi2-\arctan \frac 1x,\quad x>0. $$

Comment: oh. I didn't know that. Thanks!

Comment: @Eliads You are welcome.

Comment: To see why, look at a right triangle with legs $1$ and $x$. One of the angles is $\arctan(x)$ and the other is $\arctan(1/x)$ and these add up to $\pi/2$.

Comment: @martycohen cool! Thanks. I wanted to why it's true.

Comment: @OlivierOloa there's something I still don't understand. Before the substitution the sum was divergent, but after it , it became convergent. How is that?

Comment: @Eliads It has never been divergent, the first argument of $\arctan$  that is $\frac{3n^2}{2n+1}$ tends to $\infty$ *but* one may recall that $ \lim_{x \to \infty} \arctan x= \frac \pi2.$

Comment: Oh I see it now. I got confused by something else. 
Thank you very much, I understand it now!

Comment: It is not convergent, but it is bounded.

Answer (score 1):

As $n\to\infty $ we have $arctan(\frac{3n^2}{2n+1})\to \frac{\pi}{2}$ so this summation gets $\sum_{n \\ sufficiently \  \ \ large} (-1)^n\frac{\pi}{2}$ which is bounded but never converges.

Comment: You need to say more...